# Insert Javascript files into odoo without replacing others

Tags: fullcalendar, odoo, fullcalendar-scheduler

I try to build an odoo module with a recent fullcalendar version.
My module works as design with this import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- vim:fdn=3:
-->
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="schedule_tpl" name="web_schedule assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web_schedule/static/src/css/web_fullcalendar.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web_schedule/static/lib/fullcalendar/css/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web_schedule/static/src/css/scheduler.min.css"/>


                <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_schedule/static/src/js/moment.min.js"></script>                                        
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_schedule/static/lib/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_schedule/static/src/js/scheduler.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_schedule/static/lib/fullcalendar/js/fr.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_schedule/static/src/js/web_schedule.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Problem, the calendar avalaible in messaging does not work anymore, I have issues with date format and so on. If i uninstall my custom module, this calendar works fine.
So, how i can import fullcalendar files to be used only in my module ?

thanks